# Setting Custom Shell via WMI

Tags: c#, windows, shell, embedded, industrial

I'm trying to set a custom shell in Windows 8.1 IND with the additional lock down features that come with this version of Windows.

I can successfully create the required entries in the Lock Down Manager and turn the custom shell on and off no problem via c# and WMI.

Because we're planning on deploying to a great number of devices, I want to problematically apply the custom shell setup too.

I'm using the [WMI Code Generator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8572) to aid me in accessing and set the correct values.

However, both the WMI Code Generator and my C# app both crash when attempting to run the code generated by the generator to do this.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was
out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: path
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.ManagementObjectCTOR(ManagementScope sc
ope, ManagementPath path, ObjectGetOptions options)
   at WMISample.CallWMIMethod.Main()
```

**Code Sample:**

```
public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObject classInstance = 
                    new ManagementObject("root\\StandardCimv2\\embedded", 
                    "WESL_UserSetting", null);

                // Obtain in-parameters for the method
                ManagementBaseObject inParams = 
                    classInstance.GetMethodParameters("SetCustomShell");

                // Add the input parameters.
                inParams["DefaultAction"] =  3;
                inParams["Shell"] =  "C:\\Dash\\someapp.exe";
                inParams["Sid"] =  "S-1-5-21-2560287794-1129801719-3036876794-1001";

                // Execute the method and obtain the return values.
                ManagementBaseObject outParams = 
                    classInstance.InvokeMethod("SetCustomShell", inParams, null);

                // List outParams
                Console.WriteLine("Out parameters:");
                Console.WriteLine("ReturnValue: " + outParams["ReturnValue"]);
            }
            catch(ManagementException err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while trying to execute the WMI method: " + err.Message);
            }
        }
```

There is no path mentioned in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449336(v=winembedded.82).aspx). Can anyone advise why the code isn't setting the custom shell?

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I solved this problem by turning on the shell launcher as specified here: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt571994%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  It's under the "Turn on Shell Launcher" section.